# Why does Kaworu tell Shinji that Shinji'd be killed, if Shinji doesn't kill Kaworu?

Tags: neon-genesis-evangelion

Said around 21:36 of the directors cut, nearby to the iconic scene:

[image]

Comment: To help potential answerers and future viewers, could you [edit] and mention the episode number and the work's title?

Comment: Okie I'll add in time